# No music playback on Ubuntu Phone when # in filename

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, encoding, music-player

When I want to play an mp3 file with an '#' in its filename on my Ubuntu Pone Aqaurius E5 there is no sound and the track time and playback time stays 0:00. I can still move the slider though. I am using the default music app http://launchpad.net/music-app

How do I fix the problem? Renaming all the files is annoying.